# Как в компоненте Vue, хранить данные которые не нужно отслеживать?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vue.js

В Vue есть объект data, который как я понял хранит реактивные данные т.е. те данные изменение которых он отслеживает и меняет их в шаблоне. Как я понимаю это требует дополнительных ресурсов. По этому у меня возник вопрос, куда я могу записать в компоненте те данные которые не требуют отслеживания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете просто в объект компонента писать, типа вот такого:

```
...
data(){
...
},
myObj: {
 a: 'foo',
 b: 'bar'
}
}
...
```

Обращаться в компоненте вот так: `this.$options.myObj.a`

Comment: Евгений, с Вами можно как-то связаться?

Comment: Добавил контакты в профиль.